# How can I automatically let my Windows boot and shutdown?

Tags: windows, boot, automation, shutdown, hibernate

I want my PC to boot at 9am and shutdown at 10pm every day, is there a way to do that on Windows? Of course maybe don't go off completely, but hibernate or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start it, look at the BIOS settings. If the PC isn't too old, you should be able to set a start timer.

To shutdown, get a copy of `shutdown.exe` and add a new "Task" that runs at 10pm. Note that shutdown will fail if some application doesn't want to be shut down (i.e. when they display "Unsaved changes. Really Quit?" or something)

Comment: +1 that's pretty much correct. You can use `-f` with `shutdown` to force programs to close (but, if they don't want to close there's probably a reason - ie, they might be trying to save something). One thing you can do is a non-forced shutdown at the desired time, and schedule `-f` shutdown 15mins later.

Comment: +1 for both comments. shutdown.exe should come standard with XP and above. Open up a command line (Start> Run : type cmd and hit enter) and type in "shutdown /?" that will tell you all you need to know for shutdown commands. I usually use "shutdown /s /t 3600 /f" to turn my computer off in an hour. I usually have music playing when I go to sleep at night.